# Equilibrium on finger crimp

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, free-body-diagram, equilibrium

[image][image]

The diagram shows the second finger bone when a climber is hanging by the crimp hold of one hand (i.e. static equilibrium). $F_{v}$ and $F_{h}$ are force components derived from the weight and normal force against the wall and $F_{t}$ the force applied to the second finger bone due to the tendon.

How can it be in static equilibrium if there's no force with a negative component along the y axis?

Comment: It would help if you told us what $\vec F_{\rm c}$ is and stated which book the diagram came from - Halliday & Resnick? Ii is stated that the diagram is simplified and does not show all the forces acting at the top of the bone because that is the point about which moments will be taken and any forces there will not contribute to the moments calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Weight is the force which will balance the forces in Y direction resulting in equilibrium.

Comment: This isn't really an answer.

Comment: But I can't add a comment as I wanted to due to my less reputations.

Comment: @Gert But it is the answer. It’s even stated in the question that $F_v$ is derived from the climber’s weight. (It isn’t a comment: it doesn’t suggest improving the question.)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

for a static equilibrium  (2D case) , you have three equations to obtain the three unknows $~F_v~,F_h~,F_n~$

starting with the vectors components in $~ x'~,y'~,z' $ system

$$\vec F_t= F_t\begin{bmatrix}
  -\sin(\alpha) \\
  \cos(\alpha) \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\\
\vec F_c= F_c\begin{bmatrix}
  \sin(\beta) \\
  \cos(\beta) \\
  0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

from here you obtain the vectors components in $~ x~,y ~,z$ system

$$ \left(\vec F_t\right)_I=\begin{bmatrix}
  F_{tx} \\
  F_{ty} \\
  F_{tz} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf R\,\vec F_t\\
\left(\vec F_c\right)_I=\begin{bmatrix}
  F_{cx} \\
  F_{cy} \\
  F_{cz} \\
\end{bmatrix}=\mathbf R\,\vec F_c$$
where   $\mathbf R~$  is the the transformation between $~x' ,y',z'~$ and $~x ,y,z~$

$$\mathbf R= \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \gamma \right) &\sin \left( 
\gamma \right) &0\\ -\sin \left( \gamma \right) &
\cos \left( \gamma \right) &0\\ 0&0&1\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

take the sum of the forces along x-axis  and y-axis

$$\sum F_x=F_{tx}+F_{cx}-F_n+F_h=0\tag 1$$\
$$\sum F_y=F_{ty}+F_{cy}-m\,g+F_v=0\tag 2$$

the third equation is the sum of the torques about point A

$$\sum \tau_A=m\,g\,a-F_n\,H+\tau_{Fc}+\tau_{Ft}=0\tag 3$$

where

$$ \tau_{Fc}=F_c\,d\,\sin(\beta)\\
\tau_{Ft}=-F_t\frac{2\,d}{3}\,\sin(\alpha)$$

with  equations (1),(2),(3) you obtain the solution for
unknows $~F_v~,F_h~,F_n~$

$$F_v=F_{{t}}\cos \left( -\gamma+\alpha \right) -F_{{c}}\cos \left( \gamma+
\beta \right) +mg\\
F_h={\frac { \left( 3\,H\sin \left( -\gamma+\alpha \right) -2\,d\sin
 \left( \alpha \right)  \right) F_{{t}}}{3\,H}}+{\frac { \left( -3\,
H\sin \left( \gamma+\beta \right) +3\,d\sin \left( \beta \right) 
 \right) F_{{c}}}{3\,H}}+{\frac {m\,g\,a}{H}}\\
F_n={\frac {3\,mga+3\,dF_{{c}}\sin \left( \beta \right) -2\,dF_{{t}}
\sin \left( \alpha \right) }{3\,H}}
$$